# How to slice and apply functions on row intervals in a pandas dataframe when the position of the intervals are defined by list of indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(1,10,1),'col2':range(100,1000,100)})

   col1 col2
0   1   100
1   2   200
2   3   300
3   4   400
4   5   500
5   6   600
6   7   700
7   8   800
8   9   900
```

These are the start and end indices of my intervals:

```
sta_idxs = pd.Series([3,6], index=['col1','col2'])
end_idxs = pd.Series([5,7], index=['col1','col2'])

sta_idxs         end_idxs
col1    3        col1     5
col2    6        col2     7
dtype: int64     dtype: int64
```

I would like to sum the numbers between index 3 and 5 in col1 (4+5+6) and between index 6 and 7 in col2 (700+800).
The expected results would be:

```
col1 15
col2 1500
```

I am looking for a vectorized solution to avoid looping through columns.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think ypu are looking for something like this`df1.loc[end_idx[0]-2:end_idx[0]]['col1'].sum()` and `df1.loc[end_idx[1]-2:end_idx[1]]['col2'].sum()` but I am not sure how you want to represent them

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The problem is that I wouldn't like to loop through column by column and slice the resulting series and then append the results to a new series. (If I understood your suggestion well.) I am looking for a vectorized solution.

Comment: could you please provide a more examples for this so I could better understand what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

For general situation and a little overkill, we can use `rolling` and `lookup`:

```
pd.Series(df1.rolling(3).sum()
             .lookup(end_idxs, end_idxs.index),
          index=end_idxs.index)
```

Output:

```
col1      15.0
col2    2100.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, It saves my day, and it's very concise!  Applying a function fancier than sum() on the whole database with a rolling operation is an overkill indeed. Also can't be applied to the second part of my question about variable-length intervals. Still, it was useful advice!

Comment: Your answer revealed an implicit error in my example suggesting equal interval sizes for all columns. Your solution was correct for that special case, but that wasn't my original intent. Sorry. I have corrected my examples to better reflect on the general problem.  Can I avoid iterating columns?